# Subscribe to an Observable once and use its value multiple times in RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2, kotlinx.coroutines

I am using flatMap as  an indicator then should I fire another network request.

```
  Observable<ResponseBody> secoondRequest =  firstRequest.flatMap(responseBody -> {
            return RetrofitFactory.create().setIssuingCountry(countrySetRequest1);
        });
```

The problem is that I have more than one secondRequest Observable, so my firstRequest executes multiple times.. I only need for it to **trigger once** for all other observables..

```
  //This should not call firstRequest again, if it was already triggered once
Observable<ResponseBody> secoondRequest2 =  firstRequest.flatMap(responseBody -> {
            return RetrofitFactory.create().setIssuingCountry(countrySetRequest1);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what your usecase is. So I am assuming that you have multiple requests that depend on the response of the first request. That is

request1 <- request2, request3, request4....
One possible way to solve problem is as below

```
Observable<ResponseBody> firstRequest = firstRequest();

Observable<ResponseBody> finalRequest = firstRequest.flatMap(responseBody -> {
 return RetrofitFactory.create().setIssuingCountry(countrySetRequest1)
.merge(RetrofitFactory.create().setIssuingCountry(countrySetRequest1))
.merge(RetrofitFactory.create().setIssuingCountry(countrySetRequest1))
.merge(RetrofitFactory.create().setIssuingCountry(countrySetRequest1))
...
}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for my bad... Actually what I meant is that firstRequest() should be called once, but it will affect multiple other requests and act as a trigger. For instance I have 5 finalRequests. Each of them dependends on firstRequest to finish, before creating that finalRequest. But as soon as firstRequest finishes, it should trigger all other 5 requests, without calling itself every time.. because right now situation is this: first request creates network request 5 times, and after each firstRequest returns response, finalRequest executes. I need only one firstRequest, but 5 finalRequests

Comment: in the example I provided, the four requests inside the flatmap will start only when the first request finishes and first request will be called only once. You will get a final observable which emits data from the four requests as they complete. But it wont necessarily be in order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your `firstObservable` in a variable and use `share()` and `replay()` to make it execute once (first observable will be subscribed once) from multiple source, but its value is emitted to multiple second observables.

```
Observable<Something> firstObservable = firstRequest().share().replay()
Observable<ResponseBody> secoondRequest2 =  firstObservable.flatMap(responseBody -> {
        return RetrofitFactory.create().setIssuingCountry(countrySetRequest1);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but strangely my first request had not been executed at all. I subscribed as always, but initial request has not been send...

Comment: Are you subscribing to the `secondRequest` correctly?

to be exact, you need `someObservableThatYouWantToShare.share().replay().flatMap { secondObservable }.subscribe( {...}, {...}`

Comment: Yes, I have tried. Still no requests at all. Attaching code snippet:
https://gist.github.com/wellbranding/557e176285d920335570296c36dda869

Comment: Could you log the errors using `Throwable.printStackTrace()` on each RxJava `onError`?